# Linux clients + Windows server - Assigning computers to users/groups

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, windows-server

I have a windows server and ubuntu clients. My clients already joined the active directory but I cannot figure out how I could assign certain users to certain computers. I don't want all the domain users to be able to log in on every computer. How can I do that?

Comment: Which AD client software are you using? Samba winbindd? sssd? nslcd?

Comment: I'm using likewise-open